# Train an NN using SIFT information

Tags: opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network, sift

I have keypoint information using the SIFT descriptor for an image dataset/s. I need to train a network to predict the characteristic scales (labels) of the keypoints. My question is regarding the input data to the network. How can I feed the input image and the keypoint information (datapoint) with the corresponding label into the network? Can I make use of the coordinates of the keypoint as an anchor point in an image? and if yes, how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.